# how to sanitize object keys in JSON for conversion to XML

Tags: javascript, json

I need to remove any slashes from all keys (and sub keys) in a JSON structure in order to convert it to XML, where a slash cannot occur in a tag name.

```
"langServices": {"en/ENGLISH_ONLY": "English"}
```

I imagine something along the lines of

```
var finalData = jsonstr.replace("en/", "en-");
```

, replacing all slashes with a dash. So it should also work for this: `{"can/cancel" : "true"}`, where I don't know what string will come before the slash.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've shared?

Comment: i can't convert that to xml?

Comment: Please respect my wishes before grading...

Comment: "Please respect my wishes before grading..."  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Amy it means that do not down vote as he/she has valid question according to him/her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var jsonIn = {
  "some/other/key/with/slashes": "foo bar baz",
  "langServices": {
    "en/ENGLISH_ONLY": "English",
    "can/cancel": "true"
  }
};

function sanitizeKeysRecursively(objIn) {
  Object.entries(objIn).forEach(function(kv) {
    var sanitizedKey = kv[0].replace(/\//g, "-");

    // call the function recursively on any values that are objects
    if (typeof kv[1] === 'object') {
      sanitizeKeysRecursively(kv[1]);
    }

    // set the sanitized key and remove the unsanitized one
    if (sanitizedKey != kv[0]) {
      objIn[kv[0].replace(/\//g, "-")] = kv[1];
      delete objIn[kv[0]];
    }
  });
}

sanitizeKeysRecursively(jsonIn);
console.log(jsonIn);
```

Comment: This is not a common format for every tags. what is tag name comming as `{"can/cancel" : "true"}` ?

Comment: Updated my code. It will apply to the `"langServices"` keys only, but replace any occurence of a slash with a dash.

Comment: Let me know if by "tag names" you actually mean "object keys" and need it to apply to the whole JSON structure!

Comment: thanks  for reply . Yes, I need remove `/` from whole JOSN tag names.

Comment: I updated my snippet again with a function that sanitizes all object keys in a given JSON structure recursively.